# Some get API functions are not supported by my HT-CT800

Tags: sony-audio-control-api

My Device from `getInterfaceInformation`

```
{
    "id": 33,
    "result": [
        {
            "interfaceVersion": "4.0.0",
            "modelName": "HT-CT800",
            "productCategory": "homeTheaterSystem",
            "productName": "Bar",
            "serverName": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Firmware version is `M39.R.0377`

I tried use `getSoundSettings` with

```
{
    "method": "getSoundSettings",
    "id": 73,
    "params": [
        {
            "target": ""
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.1"
}
```

and it returns

```
{
    "error": [
        12,
        "getSoundSettings"
    ],
    "id": 73
}
```

also use `getSupportedApiInfo`
still return

```
{
    "error": [
        12,
        "getSupportedApiInfo"
    ],
    "id": 5
}
```

These methods work:

- getInterfaceInformation (v1.0)
- getPowerStatus (v1.1)
- getSWUpdateInfo (v1.0)
- getSystemInformation (v1.4)

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sending the message to the correct path for "getSoundSettings" it should be http://{{IP}}:10000/sony/audio and for "getSupportedApiInfo" it should be http://{{IP}}:10000/sony/guide

Comment: @David-Sony My bad.I forgot libs are different.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct path `http://{{IP}}:{{port}}/sony/{{lib}}` for the method you are calling for "getSoundSettings" it should be `http://{{IP}}:{{port}}/sony/audio` and for "getSupportedApiInfo" it should be `http://{{IP}}:{{port}}/sony/guide`.

You find the lib for each method listed in the API reference https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/api-references/api-overview-2